# Elasticsearch Sorting fields anomaly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

Trying to sort a list on certain fields. `firstName` and `lastName` but I have noticed some inconstant result.

I am running a simple query

```
//Return all the employees from a specific company ordering by lastName asc | desc

GET employee-index-sorting
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "companyId": 3179
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "lastName.keyword": { <-- Should this be keyword? or not_analyzed
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the result why would **van der Mescht** and **van Breda** be before **Zwane** and **Zwezwe**?

I suspect there is something wrong with my mappings

```
{
        "_index": "employee-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "637467",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "companyId": 3179,
          "firstName": "Name",
          "lastName": "van der Mescht",
        },
        "sort": [
          "van der Mescht"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "employee-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "678335",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "companyId": 3179,
          "firstName": "Name3",
          "lastName": "van Breda",
        },
        "sort": [
          "van Breda"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "employee-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "113896",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "companyId": 3179,
          "firstName": "Name2",
          "lastName": "Zwezwe",
        },
        "sort": [
          "Zwezwe"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "employee-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "639639",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "companyId": 3179,
          "firstName": "Name1",
          "lastName": "Zwane",
        },
        "sort": [
          "Zwane"
        ]
      }
```

***Mappings***

Posting the entire map because I am not sure if there might be something else wrong with it.

How should i change the lastName and firstName propery to allow for sorting on them?

```
PUT employee-index-sorting
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {},
        "analyzer": {
          "keyword_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "trim"
            ],
            "char_filter": [],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          },
          "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 5,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "employeeId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "companyGroupId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "companyId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "number": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "preferredName": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "firstName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "middleName": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "fullName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keywordstring": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
            },
            "edgengram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "terminationDate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "companyName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "idNumber": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "jobNumber": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "frequencyId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "frequencyCode": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "frequencyAccess": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As [far as I know](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-request-sort.html) you should not add `.keyword` when *querying*, use just field name.

Comment: So if i take it out i get the following error...Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [lastName] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead

Comment: So, i enabled Enabling field data on text fields but still not getting the correct values.

Comment: @PeterM in the example you point at, the field used for sorting just doesn't have the `.keyword` suffix but it is indeed a keyword field.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, that in mappings `lastName` is text but with fields, however in source it is `string`. So that field can be text with object properties? So that it will index as text and also as keyword, am I right?

Comment: @PeterM the way it works is that the `lastName` field is of type `text` and the synthetic `lastName.keyword` field is of type `keyword`. But in the source you only see `lastName`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For sorting you need to use `lastName.keyword`, that's correct, no need to change anything there.

The reason why `van der Mescht` and `van Breda` are before `Zwane` and `Zwezwe` is because sorting on strings happens on a lexicographical level, i.e. basically using the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and uppercase characters happen before lowercase ones, so words are sorted in that same order. But since you're sorting in `desc` mode, that's exactly the opposite:

- `z...`
- ...
- `van der Mescht`
- ...
- `van Breda`
- ...
- `a...`
- ...
- `Zwezwe`
- ...
- `Zwane`
- ...
- `Z...`
- ...
- `A...`

To fix this, what you simply need to do is to add a [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) to your `lastName.keyword` field, i.e. change your mapping to this and it will work:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {},
        "analyzer": { 
          ...
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          ...
        },
        "normalizer": {             <-- add this
          "lowersort": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        ...
        "lastName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowersort",   <-- add this
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, did not realize that the upper and lowercase would have such an effect. But now I know. So seems to be working will be testing some other scenarios quickly.

Comment: Thanks, Val, it is working. I found one scenario where the order does seem a bit off but I am still investigating that. But 99.9% is working

Comment: Feel free to provide more info and we'll sort this out

Comment: ok so I double checked everything and it actually seems like it is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: awesome, great !

Comment: anything else needed for the bounty ?

Comment: Nope, sorry didn't realize I had to approve the bounty. :-)